# Why is window scroll with jquery jumpy in Safari?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, scroll

On my site I have an animation at the top of the page that animates based on the user scroll. At/after a certain point the animation finishes and the users scroll continues. I'm achieving this by getting the `scrollTop` position while scrolling and adjusting the `top` position of the other section of the page:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
     var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop(); 
     sections.each(function(){
          $(this).addClass('no-scroll');
          $(this).css({
               'top': windscroll
          });
          $('#arrow .wrap').addClass('no-scroll');
     });
});
```

I tried doing the top adjustment to my page container assuming the `each` was causing the jumpiness but I got the same result. I also tried a "throttle/debounce" plugin called [jQuery throttle / debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) but it didn't help. Playing with the options either made it worse or didn't make any changes.

I do notice there is some jumpiness in Chrome (another Webkit browser... could be a related issue?) but it's a fraction as noticeable in Chrome. I can justify the jumpiness in Chrome but Safari is so bad I'd like to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running into the same problem, I've created a jsFiddle for it:

[Very simple scrolling](http://jsfiddle.net/xc1pzeLp/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#main').scroll(function(){
        $('#two').css('top', $('#main').scrollTop());
    });
});
```

I understand if this happens with many elements or complex calculations, but in this example it is only 3 divs and the scrolling in Safari is appalling.